# How to setup an s3 bucket and DO droplet on the same domain

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, vue.js, digital-ocean

I have a digital ocean droplet that serves my Ghost blog and currently it is located on blog.tomorrow.tcff.co. I have an s3 bucket holding a Vue.js project that is located on tomorrow.tcff.co.

I am trying to setup my website like this:

tomorrow.tcff.co -> s3 bucket
tomorrow.tcff.co/blog -> the DO droplet

The vuejs project will have all of its own routes and so will the blog.

Is this possible? I remember reading about Nginx reverse proxy, but I think that indicated there being two seperate servers, and for my project the second "server" is an s3 bucket.

Any help, advice, or links to this problem will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!